How to format HTML files with tera template snippets?
Especially in VS Code.
There's Tera extension, but it not works now.
Once installed, I tried to use Ctrl + Shift + P but there's no relevant options.
I don't mind if any binary formatter works, thanks for recommendation!

Currently, I have found that the best formatter to use for Tera templates is Twig Language 2.
Set it up as follows:

Install the Twig Language 2 extension
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mblode.twig-language-2

Bind HTML to the twig language.
Add the following settings inside your project at .vscode/settings.json


{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.html": "twig"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "twig": "html"
    },
    "[twig]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "mblode.twig-language-2"
    }
}


After that, HTML files should automatically be detected as HTML(Twig).



